# How to automatically update boolean in database after a certain amount of time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

so I've been setting up a website, Iv'e now implemented the "premium" membership which automatically re news every once a year with stripe. In my database, I have `business` as a boolean and `expires` as a string.

Here is my code for my SubscriptionsController:

```
class SubscriptionsController < ApplicationController

before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:new, :create]

def new
end

def create
    token = params[:stripeToken]
    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
        card: token,
        plan: 1,
        email: current_user.email,
        )

    current_user.business = true
    current_user.stripeid = customer.id
    current_user.expires  = 1.year.from_now
    current_user.save       #Create a one year from now expiry, when date == expires current_user.business = false

    flash[:success] = "You've successfully subscribed, you have been charged $159."
    redirect_to current_user #Add redirect to dashboard once implemented
end

def update
    @user = User.find_by(:id)
    if Time.now >= @user.expires
        @user.business = false
    end
end

def logged_in_user
  unless logged_in?
      store_location
      flash[:danger] = "Please log in to view this page."
      redirect_to login_url
  end
end 
end
```

Essentially, what I would like to do is what I made in my `def update`, however I know that won't work. But maybe there is a way to make an argument like this in my database?

Database I'm using is `postgresql`
Payment processor is `stripe`
User model/authentication system is `custom` and not `devise`

Thanks everyone :)

Comment: Still haven't managed to get this working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a gem named `whenever` which fulfils the requirement for you.

**This will run a `cron-job(a task)` when ever you schedule it.**

**Steps:**

```
$ gem install whenever
Or with Bundler in your Gemfile.

gem 'whenever', :require => false
Getting started

$ cd /apps/my-great-project
$ wheneverize .
This will create an initial config/schedule.rb file for you.
```

**Examples:**

```
every 3.hours do
  runner "MyModel.some_process"
  rake "my:rake:task"
  command "/usr/bin/my_great_command"
end

every 1.day, :at => '4:30 am' do
  runner "MyModel.task_to_run_at_four_thirty_in_the_morning"
end

every :hour do # Many shortcuts available: :hour, :day, :month, :year, :reboot
  runner "SomeModel.ladeeda"
end
```

[This link gives you complete detail](https://github.com/javan/whenever)

Comment: Thankyou :) I just was reading another thread on here explaining the same. This is what I was looking for.

Comment: No mentions, have a nice day. :-)

Comment: Hi, not sure if you could help. But I have tried using `rails runner` in `schedule.rb`  However, this isn't working when I put in my `User.rb`        `def active_users
        @user = User.find_by(:id)
        if Time.now >= user.expires
            user.business = false
        end
    end`  This doesn't seem to be working

Comment: Have you completely gone through the doc, and made the initial setup?

Comment: [This will be help ful](http://eewang.github.io/blog/2013/03/12/how-to-schedule-tasks-using-whenever/)

Comment: I tried setting up a rake task, however isn't working. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. If someone could point me in right direction to going about it would be great :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by scheduling code to run in the future, either as a cronjob or some other mechanism.

However a better solution may not have a boolean column at all. Given that `expires` is a date column (the convention would be to called it `expires_at` to make that clear), you could remove the `business` column from your table and add

```
def business 
  expires > Time.now
end
```

To your model instead, which would tell you if an individual user was expired or not.

Similarly, a scope such as

```
scope :active, -> { where("expires > ?", Time.now) }
```

Would you allow you to query the database for unexpired users.

If you want to do some extra work (eg send an email notification) at point of expiry then this wouldn't work, but if you just need to update the boolean then this dodges the scheduling issue entirely.

Comment: I don't understand how this would work? Expires should be greater then current time because it is one year ahead of current time at date of purchase. It also doesn't explain how updating my `User model` with that changes the value of the boolean? If you could elaborate that would be great :) I'm still having issues with this

Comment: The idea is to not have a business column in the db at all - that way it doesn't need updating

Comment: Okay, now If I had an expires_at in the database. This still wouldn't solve the issue, because I would have to have the database to somewhat recognise a user is not active if `Time.now` is greater than or equivalent to the `expired_at` time. I would need an argument somewhere for this. If I could do this directly in the database somewhere that would probably solve it.

Comment: Why does the database need to recognise this? Change your queries to query on expires_at rather than business (or define scopes that do that). You could use a view to add a calculated business column but that seems overkill to me.

Comment: So I get what your saying, but how do I differ between an active business user and a normal user. By just making the user expire_at a certain time the application will just assume the user is still a business or in this case the expiry won't mean anything to the controller. Could you give an example, sorry I've been doing my head in with something that seems so simple.. Thanks :)

Comment: That's what the business method does, unless I've completely misunderstood your use case

Comment: Also that scope isn't working out, Iv'e made a scope in my User model and tried running it from the console but I just get a `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying <=
LINE 1: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (expires <=)
                                                     ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.`

Comment: That doesn't look like the scope I typed - you're missing the placeholder and time argument.